# Multithreading and recursion

Tags: multithreading, recursion

so I've got this multithreaded, recursive application. It's coded in Pharo Smalltalk but the logical solution to the issue is likely to be the same across most languages.

I have 4 of the same process running relatively simultaneously. It's the last iteration of a recursive call. I'd like to print the result calculated by my recursive function (it's a dictionary being modified in the argument of the recursive function/message). The issue I'm facing right now is that the print is called in the base case terminator of the recursion, so the result is printed 4 times.

I tried setting a global variable which allows for me to print the result of the process which finishes first, but of course that means that the result is wrong. It needs to print the result of the last process to execute of all the processes in that last iteration of the recursion.

How could I go about this without going too deep into the Process class? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Instead of setting, have each process [atomically] increment the global. When the count gets to `4` [# of processes], then do the print as everybody will have completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the number of threads? (Supposedly, 4)
Then you can use an atomic long (in java, for example):

```
AtomicLong myAtomicLong = new AtomicLong(0);

...
...

// do my work
if (totalThreadCount == myAtomicLong.getAndIncrement() -1)
{
   //my print
}
```

The increment and get is atomic, so the last thread to want to print, will get there and the condition will be true after all other threads have finished their jobs. Please notice that it is important to place the increment and check after the job, is done.

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense - I'll flag your response as the answer. Thank you! Any clue about an implementation in Smalltalk?